# AppBuilder doesn't recognise Android devices

Tags: android, debugging, telerik, adb, telerik-appbuilder

I'm trying to develop an app on Telerik AppBuilder and want to run it on physical devices. Even if I connect the devices with USB, AppBuilder doesn't recognise and the devices don't show up. I have enabled 'USB debugging', chosen 'MTP' as USB connection mode. I tired restarting everything, still the same issue. Is there something to do that I'm missing?

But when I connect my iPhone, it appears on devices list. However, I can't run and debug since I have no certificate from Apple.

So, what can be the problem for detecting the device? Thanks.

Comment: check with the android device drivers and install them.. Samsung,motorla etc... some times requires android Drivers separately.. install the on the pc..

Answer (score 0):

It could be a driver issue with your device (does it show up on your PC when you connect it?). You can check out other instructions in the [docs here](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/cordova/running-on-devices/running-on-connected-devices/google-android-devices/connect-android).